# Count nested element with a condition MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this data model:

```
{_id: 1, userId: 1, elements: [{type:'a', startDate: 2015-10-10 20:00:00}]},
{_id: 2, userId: 2, elements: [{type:'b', startDate: 2016-10-10 20:00:00}]},
{_id: 3, userId: 1, elements: [{type:'c', startDate: 2016-10-10 20:00:00}]},
{_id: 4, userId: 1, elements: [{type:'a', startDate: 2016-10-10 20:00:00}]}
```

I'd like to count all the elements for an user with a condition on the `startDate`.

for example count the number of element for `userId:1` and `startDate` greater than `2016-10-09 20:00:00`

I tried

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {userId: 1}},
    {$group: {_id: null, elements: {$sum: {
        "$cond": [
                { $gte : ['$elements.startDate', new ISODate("2016-10-09T20:00:00Z")] },
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }}}
]);
```

The result should be 2, but this is not working, do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `elements` first.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {userId: 1}},
    {$unwind: "$elements"},
    {$group: {_id: null, elements: {$sum: {
        "$cond": [
                { $gte : ['$elements.startDate', new ISODate("2016-10-09T20:00:00Z")] },
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }}}
]);
```

As a side note, ensure your `sum` stuff does exactly what you expect when there are several documents in the `elements` array.